# Office 365 Licesncing Query

Tags: sharepoint, office365, powerapps, dataverse, common-data-service

I am looking to migrate some of our business practices to the cloud and streamline the process of transferring information from field engineers to our office and vice versa.

As an example, at the moment when one of our engineers visits a customers site, they fill out a site visit report using pen and paper. This is then handed in to the office the next day for processing for invoice, follow up quotation etc. Our idea is to provide the field engineers with a celluar tablet and have the site visit report completed digitally and sent straight to the office for processing.

A bit of research indicates office365 / sharepoint / power apps would be a suitable environment for this, and so we are planning on creating a fairly simple PowerApp to collect this data and store this in either a sharepoint list or CDS table. The PowerApp would have access to existing customer information and systems and would offer the engineer drop down menues populated using lookups of the data. We would look to implement a pen input to allow customers to sign the site visit report and when completed our office would receive a notification to inform them a site visit report has been submitted.

My query, assuming the above idea is viable, is what licensing would we require to implement this? We are a small business with <10 employees and we have 2 subscriptions to Office 365 business premium for myself and my business partner - and this gives us access to all of the applications and services I think we need to make this happen. But what licenses are required for the field engineers who would need to have access to the power app and its back end out in the field, and the office staff who would need access to the data and basic office apps like excel/word along with sharepoint? Is there additional licensing required on top of the office365 business premium to run the PowerApp?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about licencing are off topic per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E3 license gives access to PowerApps non-premium stuff, I.e. share point connector, office365, the Shabang.

If you really need fancy stuff, for smaller tenants, $ 10 per user per app are the minimum operating costs, so get a license per app per engineer is the cheapest route.

If you operate from teams, F3 gives for example Project Oakdale/Dataverse for teams.